# Analyze big O relation between 5^(log2N) and N^(1/2), and how to prove it?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

It is an exercise in the book "Algorithms" by Sanjoy Dasgupta.

I guess `5^(log2N)` has more complexity because "exponential dominates polynomial". However I got confused when I tried to prove it.

I tried to calculate limitation of the ratio of the two, but failed because L'Hôpital's rule seems not work here.

So, I tried to give `log2` to the two, and get:

```
log2[5^log2N]=(log2N)*log2(5)

log2[N^(1/2)]=(1/2)*log2N
```

The result frustrated me. Does it mean that the two has the same complexity?

Hope could be pointed out where the mistaken happened?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the two have the same complexity.Big O notation is used for asymptotic analysis which means behaviour in the long run.And for very very large values **(log2N)*log2(5)** and **(1/2)*log2N** will be approximately same. You have solved the question correctly.

```
Let 5^log2N be F(N) and N^(1/2) be G(N).

log2(F(N)) = C*log2N, where C=log2(5), This means that

log2(F(N)) <=(C+1)log2N and this means that

log2(F(N)) = O(log2N), because C+1 is also a constant.

Similarly log2(G(N)) = O(log2N)

Now we have F(N) = 2^O(log2N) and G(N) = 2^O(log2N)

This is the reason they have same complexity.
```

Comment: Thank you very much!    One reason I post the question here is that the the key to the Exercise says: N^(1/2) = BigO( 5^log2N ). ( the key is not given by the author of the book I mentioned, just someone shared on the Internet but gave no proof).  So, according to your opion, the RIGHT answer is N^(1/2) = Theta( 5^log2N )?

Comment: @Explorar The book is wrong, I will edit my answer to explain the logic.

Comment: @Explorar BigO and Theta is not a contradiction, Theta implies BigO.

Comment: @Henry. Yes, you are right. they are not contradiction, but Theta is more strict than BigO. And as an exercise from a book ,the author ask the read to indicate whether f = O(g), or f =Omega(g), or both (in which case f = Theta(g)).